# Android request focus on seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar, touch-event, ontouchlistener

What i'm trying to do is to get focus from an invisible seekbar that become visible in ontouch event. Let me explain better with some code:

```
findViewById(R.id.myview).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //now it becomes visible and i need to start moving the seekbar (left or right) while keeping touch                  
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mSeekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //once touch released hide the seekbar and stop tracking
                        break;  
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? Your code would make the SeekBar visible on a user press, only to make it invisible as soon as the user lifts their finger. There would not be any opportunity to actually interact with the SeekBar unless you put in multitouch handling.

Comment: oh, so there is no way to get the focus on the seekbar while keeping touch?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code (was reading as if your SeekBar was a subview of R.id.myview). Yes, you can do that. I tested your code, it works fine.

Comment: Yes mate, it make it visibile... but while keeping touching the screen i can't get the seekbar to move right/left

Comment: As long as mSeekBar is not child View of R.id.myview, your code is completely functional. Each View listens for touches individually, so you can move the slider while holding down your other View.